# Create Email and Point to a Script or Parse Email File

Tags: postfix, email-server, parse-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Postfix to deliver ALL mail to a custom script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62547/how-do-i-get-postfix-to-deliver-all-mail-to-a-custom-script)

I've followed this [series of tuts on rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Preparing_the_Cloud_Server) and have set up a Ubuntu Lucid email server. Now, I can send emails from command line and receive emails to a file in `/var/mail`. What I'd like to do is either

- direct incoming emails to a script to parse the email, or
- find a script that will parse that file in `/var/mail`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not finding what I need through Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Postfix, have a look at [`pipe(8)`](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html). This is configured in `master.cf`.

Pipe is a delivery agent designed to handle mail accepted by smtpd which is then passed to an external command rather than delivered straight to a file.