# Postfix - How to write outgoing mail to harddrive (not internet)?

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-11.10

In order for my webb-app unit tests to work in my local development environment, namely where email delivery is concerned, I installed postfix.

Come to find out my co-workers are now getting numerous emails each time I run our unit tests. So I'd like to configure postfix so that outgoing mail is not actually delivered to the outside world, but instead written to an arbitrary directory on my filesystem.

I've done a fair amount of searching, however I haven't found a solution specific to my needs. The closest solution I can find is routing mail through a custom script, as linked below, however this has not done the trick just yet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance --

[How do I get Postfix to deliver ALL mail to a custom script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62547/how-do-i-get-postfix-to-deliver-all-mail-to-a-custom-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Add the following lines to your /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
fs_mail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=F user=%YOUR_USER_NAME% argv=tee /home/%YOUR_USER_NAME%/fs_mail.dump
```

And then add this line to your /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
default_transport = fs_mail
```

And then restart your Postfix server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

And it should save all outgoing mail into fs_mail.dump file in your home folder (replace %YOUR_USER_NAME% with your real username ;) )

Comment: Possible to add `fs_mail` as an additional channel, rather than making it the only / default one?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the smtp-sink utility that ships with postfix:

> smtp-sink -u root -d %d.%H.%M.%S 192.168.1.10:25 10

smtp-sink writes out the files with a timestamp.hex

Cheers

P.S.

You were pretty quick on the acceptance of the best answer.

P.P.S.

You specifically mentioned postfix so I mentioned smtp-sink but fakemail works better IMHO as it writes out the files as  foo@example.com.N where N is the occurrence of the same address. http://sourceforge.net/projects/fakemail/

Comment: +1 I agree, for the purpose of unit testing, fakemail is really the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

one way is redirect all mails to a local account.

# main.cf

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

# /etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/./   REDIRECT some@local.account
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, IMHO, is to create a local email address on your development machine and then configure postfix to **redirect** all mails to that address and **discard** them afterwards.

Take a look [here](http://johnleach.co.uk/words/797/redirecting-outgoing-mail-with-postfix) for some hints.